# shortcut to escape RDM

Tags: windows-10, remote-desktop

Once I use RDM full screen in windows, most keyboard commands are used within that RDM environment (e.g. `win+e` opens a new explorer on the remote machine).

How do I minimize (or close) this RDM window with ***just my keyboard*** while connected in fullscreen?

OS: Windows 10

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think that you can switch back without leaving the full-screen mode. The only way I know is to end Full-screen mode and then continue working locally:

You can exit RDP full-screen mode via <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd>.

Any key combination you press afterward will be executed on the local Windows system, not the remote Windows system connected via RDP.

Therefore you can directly use <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Tab</kbd> or <kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>E</kbd> afterwards.

Note: Pressing <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>Break</kbd> again in a non-full-screen RDP session will activate full-screen mode again.

Comment: good point, somehow I did not think of that, thx